# How does wget on macOS handle certificates?

Tags: macos, ssl, openssl, homebrew, wget

OS: macOS Big Sur

Applications: wget/openssl1.1 both via brew

I want to download some files from a webserver with wget via https, but I get the error message: `Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.` However, I can connect to this server with curl which comes with macOS. Of course I could use `--no-check-certificate`, but I'd like to understand the background and do it the proper way.

As I understand it curl uses macOS' libressl and wget uses openssl as backend. For wget I've tried to export all system root certificates as a pem file from keychain and passed this pem file via `--ca-certificate` to wget. Still the same error.

Why can curl verify the certificate without doing anything while wget can not?

```
╰─$ brew info openssl
openssl@1.1: stable 1.1.1i (bottled) [keg-only]
Cryptography and SSL/TLS Toolkit
https://openssl.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1i (8,067 files, 18.5MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2021-01-28 at 07:11:37
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/openssl@1.1.rb
License: OpenSSL
==> Caveats
A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the system
keychain. To add additional certificates, place .pem files in
  /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/certs

and run
  /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin/c_rehash

openssl@1.1 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS provides LibreSSL.
```

Edit: This is what I've tried so far:

- download via system curl -> no problem
- installed (and reinstalled) curl and wget via brew (openssl as dependency) -> both can not verify the certificate, although it is a normal root CA certificate and OpenSSL via brew claims to export all these certificates to its own storage.
- system curl with verbose option says it uses `/etc/ssl/cert.pem` for lookup, so I've tried to pass this file via `--cacert` resp. `--ca-certificate` to curl/wget -> same error.
- I also tried to export the root CA explicitly in pem format and pass it on, still not working
- Download the site's certificate manually via openssl: `openssl s_client -showcerts -servername domain -connect domain`, save the certificate as .pem and use it with wget -> works
- I also checked that the certificate key for the root ca 'Digicert Global Root CA' is present in both `/etc/ssl/cert.pem` as well as in openssl's `/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem`

I still don't understand why it won't work when OpenSSL via brew is supposed to export all the Root CAs to its own storage during install.

Comment: So you were actually able to connect to that server using `openssl s_client`?

Comment: yes, I've tried this with the system provided openssl (which is actually libressl) and the openssl binary installed via brew. Both can provide me with the certificate, but the brew openssl binary gives an 'Verification error: unable to verify the first certificate' during the handshake. Seems like it does not want to go up the verification chain, because the root ca should then be found.

Comment: Since you are not able to set up a connection with the real `openssl` (it fails with a verification error), I would try and debug that. I added a few options to the second bullet in my answer. For the trace option mentioned, you would have to build openssl yourself with the right configuration :-/. I also added an idea to leverage `gnutls`.

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information in your post to nail down the exact issue, but here are some suggestions that may help you forward:

- Download the server's certificate bundle and locally analyse its verification using [the `openssl verify` command](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-verify.html).
- Leverage [the `openssl s_client` command](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-s_client.html) to set up a TLS connection to the server directly and inspect the logged information, or dig deeper using its `debug` option(s). It has an undocumented debug option `-security_debug_verbose` that may help. If your OpenSSL is built with the the `enable-ssl-trace` option (which is not the case for the `brew` formula), you could use the `-trace` option for more output.
- Run `curl` with `-v` or some `--trace` flags to get more insight in its verification behavior.

You could do all of this with both the OpenSSL and LibreSSL versions of `openssl` and `curl` and observe the differences. The `openssl` version of `curl` can be installed with `brew`.

You could also use another (non-OpenSSL) client to set up a connection and see if it fails with more information. For example [`gnutls-cli`](https://gnutls.org/manual/html_node/gnutls_002dcli-Invocation.html), which you can install via `brew install gnutls`, provides quite a bit of debug information.

Comment: thanks for your reply, your description matches my understanding. my problem is that although I've followed the instructions for importing new certificates, it still does not work. I also exported all root certificates again and passed that pem file to wget directly.

Comment: maybe I should add that the error I get seems to concern the intermediate certificate. Also the initially bootstrapped certificates should suffice, since I did not install any certificates myself. I'm trying to contact a server with DigiCert Global Root CA and GeoTrust TLS DV RSA Mixed SHA256 2020 CA-1 as intermediate.

Comment: I removed everything that seemed irrelevant by now and trimmed down the answer to just some suggestions. I am interested in your findings...

Comment: thanks, I've updated what I've tried and what the results were